# Link the gmp library with Xcode 7.2

Tags: c++, macos, xcode7, gmp

I try to link the gmp library with Xcode. This is what I (with the help of multiple stackoverflow articles) did:

1. I downloaded the gmp file and installed it (in the default location: /usr/local ) using "sudo make install" and I checked it with "make check".
2. In Xcode I added under "Other Linker Flags" (as described in multiple articles) `-lgmp`. I also tried `-lgmpxx`.
3. In main I included `<stdio.h>` and `<gmp.h>`.

After all I still got the error: " 'gmp.h' file not found ", which indicates that the library is not properly linked. I don't see what I am doing wrong. Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you also include the flags for `-I` include and `-L` library **path**? -- And you do not use stdio in C++, either program in C or use iostream (and iomanip).

Comment: I don't know precisely what you mean but what I did is: in 'Other Linker Flags' set '-lgmpxx -lgmp'  and in 'Other C++ Flags' set '-l/usr/local/include -l/usr/local/lib -l/usr/local/'. Is this enough?

Comment: Edit: the <gmp.h> has not an error anymore, but when I include the <gmpxx.h> library I get an error for the last one.

Comment: Yes to the paths, and please consider very carefully which programming language you actually use. C++ may share a good part of its syntax with C, but so does Java. -- Is <gmpxx.h> actually present in the system, and what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: I think I installed the gmp library correctly, and the 'make check' command confirmed that. But I don't know for sure if the <gmpxx.h> is actually present. How can I check that? The error I got is " 'gmpxx.h' file not found".

Comment: Did you run `./configure` with the option `--enable-cxx`? Without that, no C++ support is compiled and installed. See https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries.html#Headers-and-Libraries and https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html#Build-Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get C++ support, you need to run

```
 ./configure --enable-cxx
```

plus any other desired/required options, see https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html, before running

```
make install
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't exactly see what you mean with "other desired/required options". Perhaps you mean the extra commands when compiling, the manual refers to it under the subject 'c++ support'. But I assume you use this after installing.

Comment: What I mean is that it depends on your wishes/demands what you additionally select from the option list. For instance, the "fat library" option for more processor-adapted implementations could be an interesting option.