# The use and the idea of integer to string conversion

Tags: c++, math, largenumber

I try to handle with big numbers in C++. One thing that I tried is installing the gmp library but this is not working properly on my computer (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101873/link-the-gmp-library-with-xcode-7-2)). So I want to try another method and that is integer to string conversion.

But I dont get the idea of that. Let me make myself clear. For example we handle with a big integer. Lets say 2^1000. When, for example, I want to calculate 2^1000 mod 10 this is not possible (so far I know) with the normal libraries of c++. So my question is: **Is it possible when converting my integer to a string** and if the answer is yes:
**How can I do arithmetic operations when I convert my integer to a string.**

Comment: You can use Fermat's little theorem to compute the remainder mod 5 easily.  Now every power of 2 is even, so you also know the remainder mod 10. (So the answer is 6.)

Comment: On the contrary. Modulo operator is easiest to calculate for numbers of format `x^y`, where x is relatively small, and y is finite number of any size. All you need to know is that `(x^y)^z = x^(y*z)`, and to apply the mod operator to the base of the power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using c++ predefined integer type, then `2^1000` is simply impossible. On your system maximum should be `2^16` or `2^32`, max `2^64` (for `long long`). If you wanted to do that, you need to use (or implement yourself - what I don't recommend) infinite-precision integers.

You can convert normal `int` to string very easily with

```
... = std::to_string(/*Your int*/);
```

If you meant you want to do something like this:

```
amazing_to_string_conversion(1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

It's not possible in any C++ implementation. The very number constant can't exist in code, it will many, many times overflow.

And if you consider implementing it yourself, it will probably K.O. you, because of very complicated calculations during division and non-trivial calculations like sqrt().

Comment: Thanks, I have a 64 bit computer so 2^64 should be possible. But what I don't understand is how an extra library like gmp could handle larger integers. How is that possible if my computer is 64 bit?

Comment: Because it doesn't use int. It works on strings and imitate integers

Comment: Okay, but it is not possible to do arithmetic operations with string right? So how can you compute then?

Comment: That's the hard part. For example you can divide your string number into parts, say, 4 byte ones. Then you can compute values for each as integers, check for over/underflows, and modify higher/lower power parts. You can also imitate completly integer system to string, but it will be much slower, and such things like A/B would take forever. Rather than trying to implement it yourself, you need to solve problems with BMP.

Comment: Big integer libraries don't typically use strings in the sense of a sequence of characters. They represent large numbers as an array of smaller ones. Doing the arithmetic operations isn't hard, conceptually, it's getting the details right that can be tricky. Just picture how you do arithmetic with pencil and paper in base 10: overflows generate a carry into the next digit. Big integer libraries do the same thing, but in base 256 or base 2^32 or whatever.

Comment: Okay thanks both! I was trying to solve problem 16 of project Euler. Therefore I needed to handle large integers. Now I got the idea how those 'large integer' libraries work I can conclude that using one of them is the best option?